# Не добавляется БД в PHPmyadmin. Перепробовал кучу хостингов, одна и таже ошибка

Tags: phpmyadmin, импорт

Ошибка
SQL запрос:

---

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `assignment`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assignment` (
  `assignment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `assignment_create` datetime NOT NULL,
  `assignment_deadline` datetime NOT NULL,
  `assignment_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_process` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_author` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_actionee` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_department` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assignment_process_group` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assignment_process_stage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assignment_process_performer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_grade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `assignment_from` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descriptions` text,
  `send_message` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `execution_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `contragent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contractor_id` int(11) DEFAULT [...]
```

Ответ MySQL: Документация

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREMENT=1478' at line 43  ![a busy cat]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
       10 Quit  
 160916  0:43:53       11 Connect   root@localhost on 
       11 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using    password: YES)
       12 Connect   root@localhost on 
       12 Query SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
       12 Query SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
       12 Query SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMATA`
       12 Init DB   mysql
 160916  0:43:54       12 Quit  
 160916  0:44:01       13 Connect   root@localhost on 
       13 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using     password: YES)
       14 Connect   root@localhost on 
       14 Query SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
       14 Query SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
       14 Query SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMATA`
       14 Query SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"
       14 Query -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
 -- version 4.0.10.10
 -- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
 --
 -- РҐРѕСЃС‚: 127.0.0.1:3306
 -- Р’СЂРµРјСЏ СЃРѕР·РґР°РЅРёСЏ: РђРІРі 14 2016 Рі., 10:03
 -- Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏ СЃРµСЂРІРµСЂР°: 5.6.26
 -- Р’РµСЂСЃРёСЏ PHP: 5.6.12

 SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"
       14 Query SET time_zone = "+00:00"
       14 Query /*!40101 SET    @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
       14 Query /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */
       14 Query /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */
       14 Query /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */
       14 Query SELECT @@lc_messages
       14 Query SELECT @@lc_messages
       14 Query SELECT @@lc_messages
       14 Query SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMATA`,  (SELECT DB_first_level FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_',  1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t ORDER BY DB_first_level ASC LIMIT 0, 100) t2 WHERE 1 = LOCATE(CONCAT(DB_first_level,   '_'), CONCAT(SCHEMA_NAME, '_')) ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME ASC
       14 Query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_', 1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t
       14 Query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_', 1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t
       14 Quit  
 160916  0:44:02       15 Connect   root@localhost on 
       15 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using  password: YES)
       16 Connect   root@localhost on 
       16 Query SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
       16 Query SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
       16 Query SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMATA`
       16 Query SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMATA`,  (SELECT DB_first_level FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_',  1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t ORDER BY  DB_first_level ASC LIMIT 0, 100) t2 WHERE 1 = LOCATE(CONCAT(DB_first_level,  '_'), CONCAT(SCHEMA_NAME, '_')) ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME ASC
       16 Query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_', 1) DB_first_level FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t
       16 Query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_', 1) DB_first_level FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE ) t
       16 Quit
```

Вышеописанное это было на Openserver'e и на нескольких хостингах. Приведенное ниже на Denver'е возникает при добавлении этой же базы через phphmyadmin
[image: :]

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

Не это я просто бд,предварительно не создал,что то я запарился, не добавляет и в денвере с этой ошибкой. 
Причем он первые три таблицы добавляет, а там их сотни.

Вот с помощью DBFourge вытащил больные таблицы:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assignment` (
        `assignment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `assignment_create` datetime NOT NULL,
        `assignment_deadline` datetime NOT NULL,
        `assignment_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `assignment_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `assignment_process` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `assignment_author` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `assignment_actionee` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `assignment_department` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `assignment_process_group` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `assignment_process_stage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `assignment_process_performer` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `assignment_grade` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `assignment_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
        `assignment_from` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        `descriptions` text,
        `send_message` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `execution_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
       `contragent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `contractor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `assignment_rule` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `assignment_indexes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
       `finished_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
       `assignment_active_tasks` text,
       `schema` text,
       `stage_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `from_api` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `process_owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`assignment_id`,`assignment_status`)
      ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
      /*!50100 PARTITION BY LIST (assignment_status)
      (PARTITION p_deleted VALUES IN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB,
      PARTITION p_active VALUES IN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
      PARTITION p_sleep VALUES IN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB,
      PARTITION p_success VALUES IN (4) ENGINE = InnoDB) */           AUTO_INCREMENT=1479 ;

Comment: Проблема похоже в запросе а не хостинге

Comment: А так и должно быть `contractor_id int(11) DEFAULT [...]`  и без закрывающей скобки в конце? и без указания ключа и  без указания типа таблицы.  Полный запрос можно написать?

Comment: А какие редакторы порушенные базы открывают, типа этой, чтобы правки внести?

Comment: Он, добавляет первые три таблицы, а дальше вышеописанная ошибка и все. То, фото, это часть базы с работающего phpadmin.

Comment: Обновил инфу в посте.

Comment: перепроб**О**вал

Comment: @Etki это ты к чему, помог бы кто?

Comment: Вот в Mysql Front тоже пишит что: Ошибка при выполнении запроса 1062. Ответ от сервера: Dyplicate primary '1' for key 'Primary''

Answer (score 3):

Первое поле в Вашем sql-файле:

```
`assignment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Единственное поле с автоинкрементом и не является ключем. Не надо так.. ))

Comment: там много чего. пока ТС не покажет полный запрос - ничего не ясно

Comment: Вполне с Вами согласен. Мой ответ основан исключительно на предоставленной информации.

Comment: А это и есть весь запрос, когда базу через Import добавляю, такое сообщение возникает и не добавляет базу.

Comment: Вот, добавил дополнение к ответу. На картинке это та база, которую я пытаюсь безуспешно импортировать на другой сервер с вышеописанными ошибками.

Comment: Причем, там она работает.

Comment: Дополнил из логов Mysql. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Что я там увидел - так это то, что у кого-то нет доступа )

Comment: Вот, вся эта злочастная база:https://yadi.sk/d/l1wflCCsuCWhB. Помогите получить доступ. А может надо в разделе phpadmin, пользователи выставить using password no и как это сделать, каки запросом?

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский Откуда мне взять этот полный запрос. Открыл кстати базу в DBFourge всетаки, оттуда, сюда что-то запостить?

Comment: @ПетровСидор, посмотрел на Ваш скрин, там ведь указана ошибка: не выбрана БД (на которую Вы накатываете миграции)

Comment: @ isnullxbh Не это я просто запарился и БД случайно не выбрал для миграции. А так и на денвере ты же ошибка. Обновил исходное сообщений.

Comment: @isnullxbh А как этот AUTO_INCREMENT подправить

Comment: @ И где должна быть закрывающая скобка в contractor_id int(11) DEFAULT [...]?

Comment: Мне, кто-нибудь ответить?